# A symbol ' gets an unexpected error

Tags: java, sqlite

I get unexpected error while executing next java code

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO fake_advert (content) VALUES ('" + content + "');";
System.out.println("sql:"+sql);
stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
```

output

```
sql:INSERT INTO fake_advert (content) VALUES ('Winni's');
org.sqlite.SQLiteException: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (near "s": syntax error)
```

How to protect from such error while inserting values?

Comment: See also:  [SQL Injection attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

Answer (score -1):

### Escape the single quote

The single quote in the string `"Winni's"` is breaking the query. A simple solution is to escape the special character in your content string.

```
String modifiedContent = content.replace("'", "''");
String sql = "INSERT INTO fake_advert (content) VALUES 
('" + modifiedContent + "');";
```

In SQL, single quotes will be escaped by using double single quotes.

### Using Prepared Statements

[Prepared statements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) are preferred over executing a SQL string directly. The code would change to something like

```
String insertStr = "INSERT INTO fake_advert (content) VALUES (?)";
PreparedStatement insertFakeAdvert = con.prepareStatement(insertStr);
```

Then the values are supplied in place of the question mark placeholders (if there are any) before you can execute a PreparedStatement object like this

```
insertFakeAdvert.setString(1, content);
```